# Packaged pdf through live cycle es2 output assembler

Tags: livecycle

How can I create a packaged pdf i.e a pdf made of swf(flex app) and xml through livecycle es2 and java api.

I have searched for the java api's for live cycle es2 but was not able to find the correct solution

Any help in this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would start by taking a look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/Services/WS92d06802c76abadb712193f912dbeb3c6db-7feb.html.